# Fixed iOS status bar overlap in PhoneGap but status bar not Showing

Tags: ios, cordova, statusbar

I developed IOS application using `PhoneGap`.Status bar overlap in Our page content,Now i Played

I am  not using storyboard, so I  can use this code in your `AppDelegate.m` in did `finishlaunching`:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
    [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
    self.window.clipsToBounds =YES;
    self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height-20);
}
```

`OverLap` issue fixed but Status bar not showing.

Please give me any idea. How to solved Status bar overlap in `PhoneGap`.

Comment: Why does someone vote +1 here? 

I even don't understand where directly the problem is right now. Can you give us a screenshot? What Phonegap Statusbar do u mean? And how does the statusbar overlap??

Comment: @Sithys first when i run my PhoneGap app in iPhone,Status Bar Overlap  my top of myContent,and i Did R&D on Google find above code  ,after add above code,Status bar  overlap and then it's not showing also

Comment: @Sithys Status bar is there but it's showing black color show data also now black so it's show showing Please tell me how to add background color on Status bar in PhoneGap

Answer (score 0):

... you have to go into your config.xml and set the Value

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
```

to `false` thats all?!